# Как исправить deadlock возникающий в коде .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Есть тестовый код, используется c# azure storage client (последний 8.1.0). Если запускать его как .Net Framework ConsoleApp проблем не возникает, но если запустить как .Net Core ConsoleApp приложение отправляет первую партию сообщений и дальше просто ждёт. Как можно это исправить?

```
class Program
    {
        static int parallelTasks = 100;
        static int count = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
        {
            var task1 = RunAsync("First task", "messages1", parallelTasks);
            var task2 = RunAsync("Second task", "messages2", parallelTasks);

            await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

            Console.WriteLine($"\r\n{task1.Result}\r\n{task2.Result}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async Task<string> RunAsync(string name, string queueName, int parallelTasks)
        {
            var account = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
            var client = account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
            var queue = client.GetQueueReference(queueName);
            await queue.CreateAsync();

            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(AddMessageAsync(i, queue));

                while (tasks.Count > parallelTasks)
                {
                    var task = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
                    tasks.Remove(task);
                }
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            var completed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            stopwatch.Stop();
            await queue.DeleteAsync();
            return $"{completed} from {name}";
        }

        static async Task AddMessageAsync(int i, CloudQueue queue)
        {
            await queue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[1024])));
            Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
            Console.Write($"\r{count}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Проверьте что лежит в SynchronizationContext.Current

Comment: В обоих случаях равен null

Comment: А если остановить его в отладчике - где потоки находятся?

Comment: Я подключил исходники клиента, все потоки останавливаются в одном месте, при попытке чтения ответа при создании XmlReader. Пытаюсь понять в чём проблема.

Comment: А что за волшебный ответ? Если Fiddler поставить - он что покажет?

Comment: Стандарный ответ queue storage (xml string). Во всех случаях приходит вылидный. Внутри azure storage client наворотили вместо асинхронного ожидания, как предпологает использование httpClient на каждый ответ цепляют Task.Factory.StartNew. Ну и соответсвенно где-то его лочат. Сейчас пытаюсь локализировать проблему и переписать на async await

Comment: Э... но зачем? Где там можно вообще использовать Task.Factory.StartNew?..

Comment: Я там глянул в код - в нем используется не StartNew, а [аналог FromAsync](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/afc5c6d99a805fb4165631ab5cfd139238b00e71/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Core/Util/AsyncExtensions.cs#L151). Это как бы нормальный подход, пусть и устаревший...

Comment: Для .net wramework и .net core подключается немного разный код https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/WindowsRuntime/Queue/CloudQueue.cs#L1137

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53813/discussion-between--and-pavel-mayorov).

Comment: А если переписать Main так: `Task.Run(() => MainAsync(args)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`?

Comment: Тоже самое к сожалению. И попытки добавить на каждое ожидание ConfigureAwait(false) не помогают. Если одновременно отправлять только 8 сообщений то отправка проходит. Пока есть свободные потоки в пуле ничего не лочится.

Comment: Хм, это уже кисло как-то. А можно попробовать укоротить до _минимального_ воспроизводящего примера? Например, если задать размер пула в 2?

Comment: 8 параллельно отправляемых сообщений и чем больше пул тем на большее время лочится. Я задал вопрос на https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/410 будут смотреть.